# After the page loads I want to dim lights and focus on form

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-modal

I am wanting to emulate something like the following. When booking.com is loaded, after a few seconds the 'lights dim' except for the search form. The functionality feels somewhat like a Bootstrap Modal but without a popup. Does anyone know of any plugins that can accomplish this? Is there a name for this sort of functionality?

[image: Booking.com focus dimmer]

Comment: No plugin needed.  Just make a full div with alpha black background, and position your container at a higher z-index.  As a web user though, please don't do this.  If you think you can assume what someone is going to do when they go to your page, you simply don't need all the other content there.  These sorts of things are hacks around big-company-problems where people fight to get homepage real estate.  It's not good UX practice, generally speaking.

Comment: Unfortunately its a request from higher up. Personally I would never touch this with a forty foot pole but big boss says jump.

Comment: I'm sorry you have to put up with that.  :-(  If you wanted to fight it, you could always show how some of your key metrics absolutely tank once you do one of those.  That's often what happens.  Your boss is (probably) wrong.

Comment: Im hoping it falls by the wayside, thanks so much for your help :)